# Custom post_type template with get_template_part

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-post-type

So, my parent-theme uses a single.php calling a content-single.php with the function get_template_part().

The code for single.php:

```
get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">
    <main id="main" class="postItem" role="main">

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>

        <?php codex_coder_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>


    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
<!--<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

I am using a custom post_type named "ourNews". Following wordpress documents, I created two files: single-ourNews.php and content-single-ourNews.php

With this, in my "single-ourNews.php" I changed the following line:

```
 <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single-ourNews' ); ?>
```

But it keeps loading the file "content-single.php". What am I doing wrong?

Other question is: How can I put a image with relative path on this custom template? I created a folder "img" and I was calling using:

But says that the image was not found. I read a little and some places said that I could not use relative path, but why not, if the theme uses? I'm confused.

Comment: So you are using the child theme, if I understand you correctly? And are you sure you are in the correct template file anyways, because if you did everything as it says above, the template should be loaded correctly. One approach how I test if the template is being loaded is that I clear the file, that I think is being loaded, and I reload the page to see if it will be blank, that way I know that one is being called. Just don't forget to Undo the clearing! ;)

Comment: Yes, thanks! I did your approach now and I was right. My child theme is loading the content-single.php from parent-theme. I have no idea why.

Comment: Do you have a file named content-single.php in your child theme?

Comment: Now, I don't have. Before doing your approach I deleted. That one that I erased (for test) was in my parent-theme.

Comment: So did you solve your issue or are you facing a new problem now?

Comment: Same problem. Still loading the file content-single.php instead of content-single-ourNews.php

Comment: Where are you inserting the code to load the template part?

Comment: Basically what I did was a copy of the two files (single.php and content-single.php) and rename to single-ourNews.php and content-single-ourNews.php (both in my child theme directory). The only change I did inside the file was in the function: <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>, as I said, I put "single-ourNews" instead of "single".

Comment: Do not use camelcase in cpt names, use only lowercase and if you need to separate words, only use underscores

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is still loading single.php that loads content-single.php

Your custom post is not ourNews. This is probably the label but not the slug. The slug is always lowercase and separated by a -. Try renaming your file to single-our-news.php.

Also, every time you register a custom post type, you should reset your permalinks options back to default and then back to what you want it to be.

For the relative path, you should not use it. You should use .'/img/name-of-image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

When using `get_template_part`, the first parameter defines the base template name (e.g. `content`, which loads `content.php`) and the second parameter loads a suffixed version if available. Therefore your call

```
get_template_part('content', 'single-ourNews');
```

is looking for a file named `content-single-ourNews.php` first, then falls back to `content.php` in case the first one is not available. I'm not sure whether the `get_template_part` function converts the suffix parameter to something like `single-ournews` or `single-our-news` before appending it to the first parameter, be sure to test a few variants of that.

I'm not 100% sure if the function behaves differently or not in child themes and parent themes. One option is to override the parent's `single.php` in the child theme and modify it directly with

```
if ($post->post-type === 'ourNews') {
    get_template_part('content', 'single-ourNews');
}

else {
    get_template_part('content');
}
```

Lastly, WordPress will look for a file `single-[cptslug].php` before loading a template for a custom post type's single view.